# How to set the LIMIT of 2 select query?

Tags: php, mysql

can you give a sample to how can i set the limit of my join query..
i used that code for pagination..

```
select a.last_name, a.first_name, a.middle_name, a.school_year,
a.student_no,a.year_level,DATE_FORMAT(date_register,'%M %d %Y/%r')date_register 
from dbo_student a 
inner join tbl_student_lc b on a.student_no = b.student_no 
order by a.last_name ASC;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
SELECT a.last_name, a.first_name, a.middle_name, a.school_year,
a.student_no,a.year_level,DATE_FORMAT(date_register,'%M %d %Y/%r')date_register 
FROM dbo_student a 
INNER JOIN tbl_student_lc b ON a.student_no = b.student_no 
ORDER BY a.last_name ASC LIMIT 0, 2;
```

The `LIMIT` clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the `SELECT` statement. `LIMIT` takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using prepared statements).

`With two arguments`, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: THUMBS UP TO YOU SIR.. sorry for the newbie question but it help me a lot. thnks again. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 0, 10
```

This will display the first 10 results from the database.

Answer (score 1):

to add limit you can try adding `ORDER BY a.last_name ASC LIMIT 0,2` at the end of query.

Answer (score 0):

Simple add LIMIT 0,2 at the last of your query like

```
ORDER BY a.last_name ASC LIMIT 0,2   //OR LIMIT 2
```

This will display first 2 records(rows) from your DB

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.last_name, a.first_name, a.middle_name, a.school_year,
a.student_no,a.year_level,DATE_FORMAT(date_register,'%M %d %Y/%r')date_register 
from dbo_student a 
inner join tbl_student_lc b on a.student_no = b.student_no 
order by a.last_name ASC  LIMIT 0,2;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from ( select a.last_name, a.first_name, a.middle_name, a.school_year,
a.student_no,a.year_level,DATE_FORMAT(date_register,'%M %d %Y/%r')date_register 
from dbo_student a 
inner join tbl_student_lc b on a.student_no = b.student_no 
order by a.last_name ASC) as t1 limit 0,2 ;
```